# A builder/parser of text-based configuration files using XSD/DTD schemas?

Tags: python, xml, parser

I thought that XSD/DTD schema would be a great way to go when trying to build or parse the many various configuration text files out in today's computing environment.

Is there such a tool that would enable the following design?

```
DTD ----------+
              |
config file --+ -- DOM/SAX Parser --> Python object
              |
Scheme -------+


DTD ----------+
              |
Python object --> XSLT-like transformation --> named.conf
              |
Scheme -------+
```